# readUTF not reading from second time in socket file transfer JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

i am trying to transfer files via socket. I've used only a single socket for communication( not according to FTP protocol i guess). The following code will transfer the **first** file successfully but is **not able to tra nsfer second file** as the **filename doesn't change but the server gets the read bytes of the new data file**. I think the problem is of the readUTF and writeUTF.

Here is my server side code. **Remember this accepts the file.Not send file.**

```
public int listenPort() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("LISTENING");
            try{
                //this.dis = new DataInputStream(this.socketClient.getInputStream());
                if( this.dis.available() != 0 ){

                String filename = this.dis.readUTF();
                this.fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/ankit07/" + filename);

                int bytesRead = (int) IOUtils.copyLarge(this.dis,this.fos); //no of bytes copied
                return bytesRead;

                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }finally{

            }
}
```

Here is my client side. **Remember this side sends the file. Not accept**

```
public void getFile(String filename) throws IOException{
            try{
                this.file = this.window.file;
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(this.socketClient.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(filename);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.file);
                int readByte = (int) IOUtils.copyLarge(fis, dos);
                System.out.println("FILE SENT : " + filename + "  Bytes :" + readByte);

                //this.socketClient.close();
            }finally{               
                //if( this.os!=null)    this.os.close();
                if( this.window.file != null) this.window.file = null;
                if( this.file != null) this.file = null;
                //if( this.socketClient!=null) this.socketClient.close();
            }
}
```

The file selections are done in other class **window**.

The method to select the file is in the **window class**. This has a public File property to hold the file and then i've called the **getFile(String filename)** to send the file name and to refer to the selected file, the client has File property to refer to the same file.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Object src = e.getSource();

    if( src instanceof JButton ){   //Browse clicked
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); 
        int returnVal = fc.showDialog(null, "SELECT FILE");
        if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                this.file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    this.sc.getFile(this.file.getName());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
        }else{
            //unable to select file 
        }
    }
}
```

Also i am not able to transfer large files like mp3 and video besides my initial problem. It would be helpful if you'd know any solutions.
Thanks you !!!!

Comment: Get rid of the available() test.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem. still it reads the first file but not able to read the next file.. the file reloads ( a refresh type of thing happens) and the filename still remains the same

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `filename`, but then you're sending `this.file`. There's nothing here to show that they're always referring to the same file. Indeed you have a RS file, in `this.window.file`. You need to sort out all this confusion.

Comment: I've added the details.Now you may look at the details

Comment: I've added the details.Now you may look at the details..The file which i am refering and manipulation are ofcourse giving the right bytes..The first file transfer is always successful..the problem starts with the second transfer and readUTF and writeUTF

Comment: Nevertheless if the file name doesn't change it's still a bug in your code. It's too complex. Change the `getFile() `method (a) to be called `putFile()`, which is what it really does, and (b) to take a `File` parameter, and (c) to use only that paramater, not any global or instance state.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @rekaszeru It provides the answer that what is being *sent* is not what the OP thinks. Do read what's written here.